# Jenkins Warnings plugin actions are not available

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I added Warnings plugin to Jenkins (2.138.2) but I don't see the post build actions of the warning plugin.

I see "Scan for compiler warnings" and many other actions, but not "Record static analysis results"

What may be the problem?

Comment: Are your jobs freestyle or pipeline?

Comment: maven and freestyle

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. For me it was enough to refresh the page after building the project. It should look like:

[image: Screenshot of what it should look like]